# Is it safe to use a battery, which voltage is slightly different?

Tags: voltage, batteries, laptop

I'm going to replace the battery on my HP ProBook 4730s laptop. As far I know, it should be 14.4 Volt. However, when connected to the voltage tester, the replacement battery shows 15.58 Volts. Is that safe?

Thanks,
Alex

[image: Image uploaded below]

Answer (score 2):

14.4V indicates the nominal voltage for a 4S (4 cells in series) battery. A fully charged li-ion cell is 4.2V. So anything upto 16.8V would be normal.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage difference should be fine.

In general, for battery packs: the pack is often powering DC-DC converters anyways, which can (and must) tolerate some input range.  Unimportant's note about nominal voltages is spot-on for [lithium-ion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery) cells.

If the pack were marketed as a "replacement" or "upgrade" pack for this laptop, then it is fine - the engineer whom built it chose compatible cells to ensure safety and longevity.

But if the pack is just some generic pack, with no claim of being compatible with this laptop, (or trying to fix your own and using the wrong cells) -- trying it could be risky.  The charger in the laptop is designed for the original pack and cell type (of which there are many types.)  Modern cells are safe if used properly, but misuse of incompatible charging/cell type can result in pack failure, excessive heating, even [fire and explosion](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=lithium+battery+explosion).

Comment: Your advice is correct BUT you have not provided more than passing comment on the key fact that a 4S LiIon pack varies from about 13V to 16.8V as it charges. You don't need to duplicate another answer, but this fact is the key issue involved. Mi

Answer (score 0):

You must have just charged it and it is decaying to 3.8V x 4 from 3.95 x 4.  Normal operation after CC charge CV for last 10% at 4.2Vx4.

Nice tester ;)

Battery normal swing is 20% around 14.4 so the MOBO DCDC converters can handle this easily.